# How do I log excel usage in SQL table?

Tags: sql-server, excel

I've tried to Google this and have not found anything. I have excel Pivot tables connected to a SQL database. I want to be able to log user data and usage to a SQL table.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2008 and above you can use a built in feature called SQL Server Audit which can log every select against a table. If you want to only log excel usage set up a view that excel uses and audit uses of the  view. Triggers don't work on select statements.